# nextjs tailwindcss zombie image

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I had an svg I was using in my next.js tailwind project, but have since removed. However, no matter what I do, delete node_modules, delete .next folder, the dev server crashes complaining about not being able to locate this svg.

```
error - ./src/styles/tailwind.css:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve './${mySVG.src}'
```

I did at one point extend the tailwind config as described [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image) for background images, but have since removed that from my tailwind.config.js. There must be somewhere this is stored but I can't find it. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you run a search in the project folder for the keyword "./${mySVG.src}" and see if it exists anywhere.

Comment: @DazlyGonsalves yes, I've done that prior to posting this and no reference exists. I simply copied the updated files over to a different folder then nuked the project and started over. Not ideal but it worked.